What would life be like in a universe with gravity that increases with distance?
We live in a universe where gravity is determined by the inverse squared of the distance between the two objects. Inverse gravity has already been explored here.
But what if gravity grew stronger with distance? Clearly, a large universe would collapse on itself, or at least attempt to. It would stop pulling on itself as much as soon as it collapses into a smaller space, allowing it to expand yet again. A smaller universe could be supported, but planets still wouldn't be able to form under their own gravity.
Interestingly, in the linear case, orbits are closed, like in our universe.

This looks like a very high concept question - "describe this universe".  What is the realistically bounded worldbuilding problem you are attempting to solve here?

See also: the strong force, which is known to grow stronger with distance. The main feature of the strong force is that this causes its confinement: due to increasing force (and thereby "strong potential energy", akin to gravitational potential energy) as distance increases, there is a finite distance limit at which it is more energetically favorable to pull a quark-antiquark pair out of the vacuum than separate the original two any further. In other words, the "gravity" you describe would be confined. This would separate star systems into non-interacting clusters.

How would stars work, if it was no longer energetically favorable for gravity to compress them to the point of causing fusion? (After all, compression would weaken the gravitational force the star is experiencing.)

@KerrAvon2055 Bit of a problem there, ho can he describe it further until this is answered? or, he could be considered to have described it already (in a way) anyway, assuming all other forces and universal constants remain unchanged that is.

@Pelinore imagine that the question was "What would life be like in a universe with gravity that decreases with the square of distance?" ie describe life in this universe - it's far too broad a question to be answerable.

@KerrAvon2055 You wot? "What would life be like in a universe with gravity that decreases with the square of distance?" is far to broad to be answerable? would you care to think that one through again perchance? the answer is obviously "the same as in this the real one, subject to all of the same expected variations of chance and environment" there's nothing broad about that, he's not asking you to detail all known life you twit, it's very clearly more on the lines of is life possible .. and maybe could life from this universe survive there if it found a way to get there.

As this question is maybe should perhaps be asked in Physics SE rather than here as something like "what's the effect on the formation of the universe  if.." not sure it would fare well if migrated as it is currently postulated though?

I admit: The question is a bit broad. However, I think it is still an interesting idea.

@pelinore this question would almost certainly be closed on PSE as not pertaining to mainstream physics. Some answerable questions may just not have a home on this network. But since it admits a short complete answer, I went ahead and gave it, even though I don't necessarily disagree with closing.

Nonexistent. Uniform distribution of mass is a stable equilibrium for such a system and there are no equilibria which are not uniformly distributed. Therefore stars never form.
Consider a toy model: a row of point masses connected by ideal springs with equilibrium length 0. The toy model is useful because springs are a real thing which has $F \propto x$. Tension on the spring can represent pressure forces and/or cosmological expansion.
If the springs are under nonzero tension (so that we have a universe at all, and not just a mass singularity that sits around doing nothing), the system distributes itself until all the springs are a uniform distance apart. Suppose we start with a uniform distribution and randomly assign velocities to all the point-masses. Whenever an adjacent pair of point-masses moves closer to one another, one or both members of the pair stretches the springs in the direction it is coming from and compresses the springs in the direction it is going towards. This causes a reaction force opposite the direction of movement, and there is no increasing force in the direction of movement to counteract the reaction force. Consequently they never accrete into clumps, but oscillate around uniform spacing.
